# PreviewTextInput Combobox requires Enter pressed twice? (Chinese characters) WPF Simulate enter keystroke

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a `combobox` that is text editable and I am using `PreviewTextInput` as the event.

I am not sure what this is called officially ,but the text entered into the `combobox` is in a state of change until return is pressed. Meaning that pressing the space bar changes the text into Chinese characters and it is possible to press the space bar multiple times to get the desired character until enter is hit and the text is finalized.

I tried to use `TextChanged` , but this fires an event every time a key is pressed and when using Chinnese characters, you can have anywhere up 8-12 or more keystrokes before text is finalized.

This image demonstrates that state of change. Pressing the space bar tabs through the drop down list until enter is pressed locking the selection. In this case 7 characters are entered `zong li` to get the Chinese character.

[image]

I can work around this by using `PreviewTextInput`, as the event does not fire while the text is in that state of change. However, when pressing enter the event is fired, but the `text string` is empty, but pressing enter again allows for correct information into the `text string`.

### My question,

Is there a way to simulate the enter key being pressed so the user only has to press enter once? Or is there a better way to achieve this? Being that this is a WPF application, I would prefer to stick to code for that.

Simple code for the event which calls a method that does everything I need it to do. I don't see the need to post the method's code as the issue is with this line `TextBoxStr = SearchNameTxtCombo.Text;` returning an empty string when enter being pressed for the first time. As stated earlier second pressed returns the correct `string` value.

```
 private void SearchNameTxtCombo_PreviewTextInput(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {            
                if (SearchNameTxtCombo.IsKeyboardFocusWithin)
                {                
                    TextBoxStr = SearchNameTxtCombo.Text;  
                    GetPartialNamesComboBox();              
                }

            }
```

And the XAML,

```
    <ComboBox Name="SearchNameTxtCombo" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
       IsEditable="True" 
       TextBoxBase.PreviewTextInput="SearchNameTxtCombo_PreviewTextInput" 
       Grid.Column="9" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,10,5"
       DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" 
       SelectionChanged="SearchNameTxtCombo_SelectionChanged" 
       IsDropDownOpen="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay}"
       ItemsSource="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=EmployeesNameNumberPairs}" 
       SelectedItem="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=SelectedEmployee}">
   </ComboBox>
```

`TextBoxBase` is used in the XAML as the `combobox` uses a `textbox` when `IsEditable` is set to true.

> When IsEditable is equal to false, the ComboBox uses a
>   ContentPresenter to display the currently selected item; **when**
>   **IsEditable is equal to true**, a **TextBox** is used for this purpose
>   instead.

[ComboBox.IsEditable Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It's because of Input Method Editor. Why don't you use TextInputUpdate event instead of TextChanged? Also event args contains details to determine current "state"

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, `TextInput` I can't get to work with this.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, I can't get `TextInputUpdate ` to fire. It seems to be a handled event???